# Regular expression to strip (double) underscore(s) surrounding a C identifier

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code snippet in python

```
import re
lines = "#define __xyz_pqr_tqe_ope_H__" 
re.sub('(__)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(__)', '\1ab\2\3null', lines)
print(lines)
```

I want to replace the starting and ending double underscore/single underscore(if possible) with blank using regex only if I see #define or #undef

That means my output should be like

```
#define xyz_pqr_tqe_ope_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some parts here:

```
import re
lines = "#define __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__"
lines = re.sub('(#define|#undef)(\s+)__?(.+[^_])__?(\s+|$)',
               r'\1\2\3\4', lines)
print(lines)
```

1. `re.sub` returns the modified string
2. Use raw strings to preserve backslashes (and you'll don't have to escape them, writing it twice (`\\`). Here, this is especially useful for `'\1\2\3'`, they won't be processed as special characters
3. The last character before `__?` cannot be an `_`

**Results** for all double/single **surrounding underscores combinations** with **preprocessor commands** `#undef` and `#define`, plus **typos** to show it won't do a replacement in these cases:

```
#undef __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:     #undef T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#undef _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:       #undef T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#undef _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:      #undef T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#undef __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:      #undef T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#define __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:    #define T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#define _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:      #define T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#define _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:     #define T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#define __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:     #define T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
#undeef __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:    #undeef __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__
#undeef _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:      #undeef _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_
#undeef _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:     #undeef _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__
#undeef __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:     #undeef __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_
#deefine __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:   #deefine __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__
#deefine _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:     #deefine _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_
#deefine _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__:    #deefine _T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__
#deefine __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_:    #deefine __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H_
```

Comment: I am using this solution only . This is working like a hell. :)

Comment: But I have one doubt . I need to see the #define or #undef and then do the replacement otherwise not .

Comment: What if it only contains __attribute__ or something like without #define or #undef ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

lines = "#define __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__"  
lines = re.sub(r'( _{1,2})|(_{1,2}$)', ' ', lines)  
print(lines)
```

**And *re* do not modify the string in-place, you should return it.**

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.strip`

**Ex:**

```
lines = "#define __T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H__" 
print( " ".join(i.strip("_") for i in lines.split()) )
```

**Output:**

```
#define T194_MTS_MB1_PROTOCOL_H
```

Comment: I want to do this only with regex . Can't i do this ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have to replace 2 underscore with a blank space you can use the below

```
re.sub('(_{2})','',lines)
```

[image]

Comment: If I have to handle single underscore and double underscore both then ?

Comment: `re.sub('(_)','',lines)` Something like this?